# In excel, how to have some cell references in the formula not change when you extend the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula in excel that refers to a few cells. When I extend this formula row-wise or col-wise, i see that these cell reference get updated which is fine.

Now, I have one of the formulas which does a `vlookup` form a table in a diff sheet. Now, when i extend this formula, i want only the local cell reference to update but the reference to the table in the other sheet on which i do a `vlookup` should remain constant. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx for a detailed explanation of absolute and relative referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append dollar sign ($) to target column/row numbers like A4 -> $A$4

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you use formulas like `vlookup` that need ranges, you can (and generaly should) use [Defined Names](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/named.htm).